# Discord Python Bot Schedule

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio, discord.py

I think I'm doing something wrong. If I try to use to print a message in console it does work but if I try to send a message to discord I can't get it to work.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import schedule
import time

TOKEN = 'xxx'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online.')

async def job():
    channel = client.get_channel('XXXX')
    messages = ('test')
    await client.send_message(channel, messages)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I modified the code but I still get this message:

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'job' was never awaited
  self._run_job(job)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `async` on all functions, not just on the on ready. The function name is also called `on_member_join`.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.send_message(member, message)
```

The reason you have to dm the member and not send a message to a channel, is because no channel is specified.

Lets say you wanted to send a message to a specific channel you would have to do:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.send_message(client.get_channel('12324234183172'), message)
```

Replace the random number with the channel id.

If you want to read more about discord.py, you could read the docs or view  a tutorial. [Discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Note: Make sure to include `import asyncio` at the top of your page.

EDIT:
Another problem is that you did `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)`. Change this line to: `await schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)`

Comment: I modified the code but I still get a RunTimeWarning